# Need advice implementing a binary heap structure in Scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, data-structures

Well I'm just learning Scala and I'm trying to implement some algorithms and data structures.

I wrote some code that aims to transform a Vector in a linear binary heap. For instance:

`Vector(8,3,4,6,2,5,7,9)` is transformed to `Vector(9,8,7,6,2,4,5,3)`

In this way, given index `i`, its parent is at: `(i-1)/2` or `(i-2)/2` depending on `i` being odd or pair.

I leave the code here, What I'm looking for is some advice on how could I improve my implementation. Or even try it out in another completely different direction.

You can use this like: `new Heap(Vector(8,3,4,6,2,5,7,9))`

```
class Heap(vs: Vector[Int]) {
  val heap = build()

  private def build():Vector[Int] = {   
    ((1 until vs.length) foldLeft Vector[Int](vs.head)) ( (accu, idx) =>
        fixFrom(accu :+ vs(idx), idx) )
  }

  private def fixFrom(heapToFix:Vector[Int], idx: Int): Vector[Int] = {
      val parentIndex = parent(idx)
      if(parentIndex == -1 || heapToFix(idx) <= heapToFix(parentIndex)) heapToFix
      else {
          val nextToFix = (heapToFix.updated(parentIndex, heapToFix(idx))) take idx 
          val fixed = fixFrom(nextToFix, parentIndex)
          val swap = heapToFix.updated(idx, heapToFix(parentIndex))
          fixed ++ (swap drop idx)
      }
  }

  def children(parentIndex: Int) = 
    (valid(2*parentIndex + 1), valid(2*parentIndex + 2))

  def parent(childIndex: Int) = 
    if(childIndex % 2 == 0) valid((childIndex-2)/2)
    else valid((childIndex-1)/2)

  def valid(idx:Int) =
    if(idx >= 0 && idx < vs.length) idx else -1

  override def toString = heap mkString " "
}
```

Update 1: Taking the advices below, I've done some changes:

```
import math.Ordering.Implicits._

class Heap[T: Ordering](vs: Vector[T]) {
  val heap = build()

  private def build():Vector[T] = 
    ((0 until vs.length) foldLeft Vector.empty[T]) ( (accu, idx) =>
        fixUp(accu :+ vs(idx), idx) )

  @annotation.tailrec       
  private def fixUp(h:Vector[T], idx: Int): Vector[T] = {
      val parentIdx = parent(idx)
      if(parentIdx < 0 || h(idx) <= h(parentIdx)) h
      else fixUp(h.updated(parentIdx, h(idx)).updated(idx, h(parentIdx)), parentIdx)
  }

  def parent(idx: Int) = (idx-1) >> 1

  override def toString = heap mkString " "
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._

def insert[T : Ordering](heap: Vector[T], newItem: T) = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def siftUp(h: Vector[T], idx: Int):Vector[T] = {
    val parentIdx = (idx - 1) >> 1
    if(parentIdx < 0 || h(parentIdx) > h(idx)) h
    else siftUp(h.updated(parentIdx, h(idx)).updated(idx, h(parentIdx)), parentIdx)
  }

  siftUp(heap :+ newItem, heap.length)
}
def heapify[T: Ordering](vs: Vector[T]) = vs.foldLeft(Vector.empty[T])(insert)

assert(heapify(Vector(8, 3, 4, 6, 2, 5, 7, 9)) == Vector(9, 8, 7, 6, 2, 4, 5, 3))
```

Comment: Not sure why val parentIdx = (idx - 1) >> 1 does work, I'll try it out.

Comment: Also, about the annotation.tailrec, the method is tail recursive, sure, but is the annotation necessary?

Comment: LOL, I was doing a stupid effort just for taking the sub-heap to fix in the next recursive call... unnecessary... just the index, pretty much as I implemented this in java.

Comment: @tailrec is not mandatory. It is something you tell the compiler like "I think this function is tail recursion", and if the compiler finds that it is not, it will issue an error. Personally I add this annotation whenever possible.

Comment: By the way, how does work the Ordering.Implicits?, I've used this as an implicit parameter, something like: (implicit ord: Ordering[T]). Then I use "ord" when needed. Are the imported implicits making some transformation to my code?

Comment: `Ordering.Implicits` enables `h(parentIdx) > h(idx)`. Without them you'll have to write `implicitly[Ordering[T]].gt(h(parentIdx), h(idx))` using my [T : Ordering] style or equally `ord.gt(h(parentIdx), h(idx))` using your (implicit ord: Ordering[T])) style

Answer (score 1):

A Vector isn't flat. It's a linked-list in itself. It has a 1:32 tree i.e. each node has 32 children. And fills them up in order.

Since you are implementing a binary heap, we know that it's a balanced tree. And we also know that when you implement inserts and deletes, the tree will change a bit. And the tree will increase and decrease in size as well.

With the above facts in consideration, I would suggest using a mutable array object as the main datatype:

```
var arr = Array[Int]()
```

By declaring it a var, it will be better suited for when the size increases and decreases.

However, if your idea is to just implement an immutable binary heap perhaps you don't need to declare it 'var', but I would still suggest using Array[Int] as opposed to Vector[Int] since you have no need for a linked list when implementing a heap.

**UPDATE (1st Dec 2012):** Figured I'd get some practice trying to implement this way using arrays, and after several hours, I got it working. Took quite some time, and has a motherload of Scala concepts:

1. How to implement Java's `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` in Scala (Ordered and Manifests)
2. Multiple Constructors
3. Using `Option`, `None` and `Some` instead of `null` values
4. Array resizing
5. Instantiating empty arrays

and probably more. It still has some scope for improvement like:

1. Using Enumeration instead of a character being passed to the constructor
2. Create a constructor that takes a `compare` function
3. Implementing the toString

but I think I'll call it done here, unless someone wants to add something more:

```
package com.test
import Ordering.Implicits._

/**
 * Pass 'a' to sort ascending or 'd' to sort descending
 */
class BinaryHeap[T <% Ordered[T]: Manifest](sortingOrder: Char) {

  def this() = this('d')//Default will be descending

  var arr: Array[Option[T]] = Array.empty[Option[T]]
  var num: Int = 0

  def doCompare = {
    if (sortingOrder == 'a')
      (idx1: Int, idx2: Int) => arr(idx1).get > arr(idx2).get
    else
      (idx1: Int, idx2: Int) => arr(idx1).get < arr(idx2).get
  }

  def size: Int = num
  def add(t: T): Unit = {
    resizeIfRequired
    arr(num) = Some(t)
    swim(num)
    num = num + 1
  }

  def remove: T = {
    if (num > 0) {
      val ret = arr(0)
      num = num - 1
      swap(0, num)
      arr(num) = None: Option[T]

      sink(0)
      ret.get
    } else {
      throw new Exception("Tried to remove from an empty heap")
    }
  }

  private def resizeIfRequired: Unit = {
    if (arr.length == 0)
      arr = Array.fill(1)(None: Option[T])
    else if (num == arr.length) {
      doResize(num * 2)
    } else if (num == arr.length / 2 - 1) {
      doResize(arr.length / 2)
    }
  }

  private def doResize(newSize: Int): Unit = {
    var newArr = Array.fill(newSize)(None: Option[T])
    Array.copy(arr, 0, newArr, 0, num)
    arr = newArr
  }

  private def swim(idx: Int): Unit = {
    val parentIdx = getParent(idx)
    if (doCompare(parentIdx, idx)) {
      swap(parentIdx, idx)
      swim(parentIdx)
    }

  }

  private def swap(idx1: Int, idx2: Int) = {
    val temp = arr(idx1)
    arr(idx1) = arr(idx2)
    arr(idx2) = temp
  }

  private def sink(idx: Int): Unit = {
    val leftChildIdx = getLeftChild(idx)
    val rightChildIdx = getRightChild(idx)

    if ((isValid(leftChildIdx)) && (doCompare(leftChildIdx, idx))) {
      swap(leftChildIdx, idx)
      sink(leftChildIdx)
    } else if ((isValid(rightChildIdx)) && (doCompare(rightChildIdx, idx))) {
      swap(rightChildIdx, idx)
      sink(rightChildIdx)
    }
  }

  private def isValid(idx: Int): Boolean = {
    idx < num
  }

  private def getParent(idx: Int): Int = {
    idx / 2
  }

  private def getLeftChild(idx: Int): Int = {
    2 * idx + 1
  }

  private def getRightChild(idx: Int): Int = {
    2 * idx + 2
  }

  def printOrdered: Unit = {
    if (num == 0) {
      println("Heap is empty")
    } else {
      (0 until num) map (x => println(arr(x).get))
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Sounds legit, I wanted to use Vector coz I read that performs well when it comes to random access. Not sure now :P

Comment: A Vector is way better than a List any day. A List is a right-leaning binary tree with the head of the list on the left node and the tail on the right node, whereas a Vector is tree with 32 nodes on each level. Hence, it needs a max of only 2 look-ups to find any of the first 2^10 or 1024 elements, 3 look-ups for 2^15 elements, 4 for 2^20 and so on. An Array on the other hand performs very well with indexed operations and I would guess better than a Vector